# Monitoring push request of PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I analyzing my application, that is deployed on Google platform. I deploy a function,that be triggered by messages published to Pub/Sub topics.
When I use monitoring to analytic, then the results are in the image below.

push_request_count=2525 < document_write=2881. push_request_count should have been >= document_write was right.

Could anyone help explain this problem ?

Comment: Please provide me more details about your problem. The subscription/push_request_count is for monitoring push subscriptions and pubsub/write_count publish requests from PubsubIO.Write in Dataflow jobs. Why should push_request_count be bigger than document_write? (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp)

Comment: Thank for your comment .Im designed architecture as follow: IoT Core - PubSub - Function - Firestore.  When  messages published to Pub/Sub topic, then messages pushed to subcription, then function is triggered. Cloud function will write document to firestore. So, I think subscription/push_request_count = document/write. But the push server retries on errors, so a given user message can appear multiple times. So, I think subscription/push_request_count >= document/write

Comment: To answer the question, more information about the ‘document write’ operation is needed. For general rules, each set/update/create operation counts a single write [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations). And also, ‘each field transform in a write operation counts as an additional write operation’ [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage#gcp-console).

Comment: Thanhk for  Yanan C' command. I use"set" to write data into firestore and document name is timestamp.I have filtered the data by "creat". I wanted to write 2881 data into the firestore, and it was correct. But the problem at pubssub confusing me.

Comment: Hello @Lai Pham, did you have a chance to check some other Pub/Sub metrics along your app subscription, like `num_undelivered_messages`, `oldest_unacked_message_age`,etc? For more reference just check out the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring#keeping_subscribers_healthy).